# pythoncomplete in vim - hardcode factory function returns?

Tags: python, vim, numpy, omnicomplete

I'm using pythoncomplete omnicompletion in vim. 
It works great when I instantiate classes directly, eg

```
import numpy as np
x = np.ndarray(l)
```

then x attributes complete correctly.

But I work with numpy and matplotlib so usually use factory functions ie

```
x = np.zeros((2,2)) 
f = plt.figure()  
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
```

Is there any way I can hard code the return types of these common functions so I can complete on the returned object. (ie set up some mappings that matplotlib.pyplot.figure returns matplotlib.figure.Figure, np.zeros returns np.ndarray etc.?

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678953/komodo-python-auto-complete-type-inference-by-variable-metadata

Answer (score 2):

Try [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim).

There's an open issue for the problem you're facing. I think there's a good chance that it will be fixed in 3-4 months time: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/372.

Jedi is also the library used behind [YouCompleteMe](http://val.markovic.io/blog/youcompleteme-a-fast-as-you-type-fuzzy-search-code-completion-engine-for-vim) and almost every other decent autocompletion plugin for Python.