# pydev code completition and duck typing in pyqt and qt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pydev, code-completion

Hello i have just installed pydev because of code completition.
my first sketch is some simple qt widget.

i'm ovverriding mouseMoveEvent:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

    mouse = event.pos()
```

now.. i know that *event* variable is a QtCore.QPoint type.. but code completition does not work.. ok i understand it: there is no hard typing, there is duck typing, in theory event could be of any possible type..

instead if i have this code:

```
point = QtCore.QPoint()
```

when i write *point.* code completition works fine (of course it knows the type without doubt!)

i want code completition also in overriding mouseMoveEvent.. what else can i do besides change language and shift in c++ or java?

**SOLUTION**:
as [gary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72911/gary-van-der-merwe) pointed me in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678953/komodo-python-auto-complete-type-inference-by-variable-metadata/1681587#1681587) this trick works:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    assert(isinstance(event, QtGui.QMouseEvent))

    mouse = event.
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678953/komodo-python-auto-complete-type-inference-by-variable-metadata/1681587#1681587  I do this alot in komodo, I'm not sure if it works in pydev, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @nkint I'll have to correct you: `assert(isinstance(inst, class))` didn't work for me, however `assert isinstance(inst, class)` works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain that this is not a problem Python, but rather with how your PyDev is set up.

There are plenty of Python IDE's available that have no problem handling the sort of code-completion you mention - such as [eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/), for instance.

So if you can't get PyDev to do the right thing, the answer is not to switch languages, but to switch IDE's.

Comment: @nkint. Yes, but I think eric uses a more pragmatic approach. It will show _all_ possible completions taken from the current document and/or the currently installed APIs rather than those specific to the current object. I don't use eric myself, but I use an editor which works in a similar way, and I find that style of auto-completion works very well for me (practicality beats purity and all that).