# Komodo 7 or 8 code completion for django

Tags: python, django, komodo

I am using Komodo 7 for writing my django/python code.

There is one thing that I really liked when I used Eclipse for my python stuff and it was that I could do :

```
assert isinstance([variable],[type])
```

and by that help eclipse determine the coding completion for the specific variable.

Is there any way to do it using Komodo ? the IsInstance trick doesn't work here.

Comment: do you mean `assert insinstance([variable], [type])`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. fixed my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer (by interjay) to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678953/komodo-python-auto-complete-type-inference-by-variable-metadata) suggests you can add hints like:

```
if 0: foo = Bar()
```

in places where you're used to using

```
assert isinstance(foo, Bar)
```

Not as pretty, of course...

EDIT: it works for me, with Komodo Edit 6.0.3 and Komodo Edit 8.0.0

EDIT: I also found [this](http://community.activestate.com/node/6566), which indicates there is no other way (and unlikely to be soon).

Comment: Well I have done some tests and I am not quite sure it doesn't work. I have other completion problems and it may work after I'll fix it. I'll get back to you on this one :)

Comment: Well I have done some tests. if 0 foo = Bar() does not work on Komodo 8. if I have something like that object = Model.objects.get(pk=1) and I'll do before or after : if 0: object = Model() it does not work. If I'll remove the line object = Model.objects.get(pk=1) completion works. seems like there is no way to do it in Komodo 8...

Comment: Anyway, you deserve the bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Go to Edit > Preferences. 
Expand the "Languages" group by clicking the [+] symbol. 
Click "Python". 
Click the little "Add..." button under "Additional Python Import Directories". 
Add the directory ABOVE your project and you should have intellisense enabled.
```

This will allow you to see code completion for your project files (Django)